# What is Biased Notation?

Tags: c, terminology, definition, notation

I have read:
"Like an unsigned int, but oﬀset by −(2^(n−1) − 1), where n is the number of bits in the numeral. Aside:
Technically we could choose any bias we please, but the choice presented here is extraordinarily common." - http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/sp14/disc/00/Disc0.pdf

However, I don't get what the point is. Can someone explain this to me with examples? Also, when should I use it, given other options like one's compliment, sign and mag, and two's compliment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A "representation" is a way of encoding information so that it easy to extract details or inferences from the encoded information.

Most modern CPUs "represent" numbers using "twos complement notation".   They do this because it is easy to design digital circuits that can do what amounts to arithmetic on these values quickly (add, subtract, multiply, divide, ...).  Twos complement also has the nice property that one can interpret the most significant bit as either a power-of-two (giving "unsigned numbers") or as a sign bit (giving signed numbers) without changing essentially any of the hardware used to implement the arithmetic.

Older machines used other bases, e.g, quite common in the 60s were machines that represented numbers as sets of binary-coded-decimal digits stuck in 4-bit addressable nibbles (the IBM 1620 and 1401 are examples of this).   So, you can represent that same concept or value different ways.

A *bias* just means that whatever representation you chose (for numbers), you have added a constant bias to that value.  Presumably that is done to enable something to be done more effectively.  I can't speak to "−(2^(n−1) − 1)" being "an extraordinaly common (bias)"; I do lots of assembly and C coding and pretty don't find a need to "bias" values.

However, there is a common example. Modern CPUs largely implement IEEE floating point, which stores floating point numbers with sign, exponent, mantissa.  The exponent is is power of two, symmetric around zero, but biased by 2^(N-1) if I recall correctly, for an N-bit exponent.

This bias allows floating point values with the same sign to be compared for equal/less/greater by using the standard machine twos-complement instructions rather than a special floating point instruction, which means that sometimes use of actual floating point compares can be avoided.  (See http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm for dark corner details).  [Thanks to @PotatoSwatter for noting
the inaccuracy of my initial answer here, and making me go dig this out.]

Comment: The IEEE 754 exponent bias is +2^(n-1)-1, i.e. it's not a power of two. I didn't read the linked article but it sounds likely that they might have been discussing this, but erroneously suggested that a bias is the value added to the represented number rather than the value added to the actual value to obtain the representation.

Comment: Also, ordering floats like ints works equally well regardless of range symmetry around zero, the key is just that there are no negative place-values as in two's complement. As I mention in my answer, two's complement nearly equivalent to a biased notation anyway. However, floating-point values are sign-magnitude; they do not work with "standard machine twos-complement instructions" unless they have the same sign, which is seldom the case in practice.

Comment: Thanks for clarification about the actual exponent bias value.  Yes, I can see how OP might have been confused if he somehow thought the bias was added to the raw number, rather than a value in the representation of the number.  Hmm, I need to go check the compare-floats-as-integer trick.

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  Yep, my memory is faulty on the topic, you can't compare arbitrary floats this way.   Revised the text.  Sure takes the zing out of the "use int compares instead of floats".

Comment: OK, +1 :) Also, just to connect our two answers, the "binary-coded-decimal digits stuck in 4-bit addressable nibbles" are the application of the excess-three encoding mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Biased notation is a way of storing a range of values that doesn't start with zero.

Put simply, you take an existing representation that goes from zero to N, and then add a bias B to each number so it now goes from B to N+B.

- [Floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point) exponents are stored with a bias to keep the dynamic range of the type "centered" on 1.
- [Excess-three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excess-3) encoding is a technique for simplifying decimal arithmetic using a bias of three.
- Two's complement notation could be considered as biased notation with a bias of `INT_MIN` and the most-significant bit flipped.